# Dispose of a BitmapImage

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Universal App which uses several `BitmapImage`s. I'm used to wrapping `Bitmap`s (in Winforms) in `using`s or using `Dispose`, but I've discovered that `BitmapImage` doesn't *have* a `Dispose` method. Is there any way to release their resources earlier than waiting for the GC to do that?

Comment: Only was to force GC is System.GC.Collect(). If it doesn't implement IDisposable it can't be disposed of before GC without forcing GC to run

Comment: @rmn36 Right. But I was wondering if I'm missing something - If there _is_ some disposing mechanism built in to it. (It seems quite unlikely that the common use of Bitmaps is to Dispose of them as early as possible, and yet have BitmapImage with no way to do that.)

Comment: Nope you aren't missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good solution : [Memory consumption of BitmapImage/Image control in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127027/memory-consumption-of-bitmapimage-image-control-in-windows-phone-8) . it's like a extension '`Dispose`' method for the `BitmapImage`

And yes, GC.Collect() is good way ..

Comment: No. The solution there is wrong. See the comments there.