# How to view an image from the web in offline mode in Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am building my first app in windows phone 7. I have an image which i am loading from backoffice. my XAML code is

```
<Button Click="Image_Click" Name="image1" Margin="-33,-16,-26,-13">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/icons/landing.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

This is a clickable image which when clicked navigates to another page.

Now as the image is coming from the web, i want this image to be viewed the next time even while in offline mode. Can anyone help me how to do this

Comment: can someone please tell help me in this regard

Comment: Can anyone solve this problem please

Comment: @ user3156298, did you take a look at the link in my answer? It looks like it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the accepted answer on this question is what you need: [Image Source and Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261114/image-source-and-caching)

When I was facing the problem myself, I did it the hard/manual way - downloaded the images myself, cached them on the file system and referenced them from there. The proposed answer seems to provide an easier way.

EDIT: The question relates to Windows Phone 8, but it looks like it applies to Windows Phone 7.5 (otherwise known as Mango). Don't know about 7, but you should be targeting 7.5 anyway (there are no phones that cannot be upgraded to 7.5)