# Free Windows phone page memory

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a simple WP8 app with 2 pages. In MainPage the user can navigate to Page2 to see a couple of images from the net. To do this I use a WebClient

```
WebClient myWebClient; 
myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(mywebsite);
myWebClient.DonwloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(myWebClient_Completed);
```

Afther that, I display the images in a StackPanel wrapped inside a ScrollViewer that looks like this

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel x:Name= myPanel/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When i try to navigate back and forth between the pages, the app crashes after several times. I believe this is a memory leak. 
My question is: What are the steps that need to be done when navigating away from Page2? 
I tried to unhook the event handler:

```
myWebClient.DonwloadStringCompleted -=myWebClient_Completed;
```

and tried to free the Images from the StackPanel:

```
foreach(var theImage in myPanel.Children){
    theImage.Source=null;
}
```

But it's no use. What am I missing? or maybe the syntax isn't right?
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it crashes because of memory leaks? Try debugging it and see what kind of exceptions you get. Also, how many images are we talking about here? How large are those images?

Comment: the exception is outofmemory exception. I tried running it using the windows store test kit and the memory does increase with time ( eventhough not monotonically). I have about 10-15 images, each just about 200-300 KB

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549980/memory-leak-changing-images-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: @user3151814 are you try to navigate back before myWebClient.DonwloadStringCompleted event ???